# How can I log someone into DotNetNuke without knowing their DotNetNuke password in an SSO scenario?

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, dotnetnuke

We are setting up a single sign on system to handle authentication and authorization among our different systems (almost all of which are not DNN systems).

The idea is that the user will be given a link by the central authentication system that redirects them to the DotNetNuke system with an authentication token.  I then need to take that authentication token, verify that it's legit, and if so log that user into DNN.  The problem with this workflow is that I have no idea of the user's password.

Previously, when I have created custom login interfaces I logged the user in by calling:

```
var portalSettings = PortalSettings.Current;
UserController.UserLogin(portalSettings.PortalId, username, password, string.Empty, portalSettings.PortalName, ip, ref loginStatus, true);
```

This obviously won't work if I do not know what their password is in the DNN/Asp.net forms authentication system.

Since this is not a new system but is a system currently being used in production without SSO, I cannot just set everyone's password to "pass1234" and require them login via SSO method only.

How can I tell DotNetNuke to log in as a user without knowing their exact password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an additional overload to the UserController that takes a "UserInfo" object.

Use `UserController.GetUserByName` to get the actual user from the system, then you can pass that object into the Userlogin method and you are good to go!

Comment: Good call, I missed that.  Thanks!